# "Наша служба и опасна(,) и трудна": нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Интуитивно чувствую, что тут два И запятой не разделяются, но не знаю, как объяснить. С одной стороны, тут перечисление с союзом И, но с другой... а вот что с другой, я не знаю))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Но с другой - это крылатое выражение уже почти стало поговоркой, фразеологизмом наподобие "и день и ночь", "ни пуха ни пера", а во фразеологизмах запятые не ставятся. Однако если поставите, всё будет по правилам русского языка.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то тут отсутствие запятой запятая объяснется по-другому.

Идея про фразеологизм мне не нравится потому, что в авторском тексте это не могло быть фразеологизмом, это про то, как Грибоедов, который из одних поговорок "Горе от Ума" составил.

Здесь, имхо, другое. Первое И относится не к "опасно", а ко всей паре опасна и трудна. В этой-то паре запятая не нужна, а в ней союз И не повторяется. Ну а между двумя группа с повторяющимся союзом И сомнений не вызывает.

То есть "структурная схема" такая:
Наша служба **и** 1) опасна и трудна, **и** 2) на первый взгляд как будто не нужна.

Поднял этот вопрос потому, что по мелкой надобности посмотрел несколько вариантов пунктуации в этом тексте - и нигде не обнаружил запятой перед "и трудна".